# Most convenient idiom to concatenate string values by key in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

Which is the most convenient way to concatenate string values in a map in Java 8 and 9. I have currently this code in a project:

```
private static void addToMap2(Map<String, ? super CharSequence> invalidMap, String key, String newMessage) {
    if (invalidMap.containsKey(key)) {
        invalidMap.put(key, invalidMap.get(key) + " and " + newMessage);
    } else {
        invalidMap.put(key, newMessage);
    }
}
```

Is this code really equivalent to:

```
private static void addToMap3(Map<String, ? super CharSequence> invalidMap, String key, String value) {
    invalidMap.merge(key, value, (s, s2) -> s + " and " + s2);
}
```

?

Are there any other better alternatives?

Comment: It seems to me, simply by reading the two pieces of code in your question, that the second one (using `merge`) is quite obviously more convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both methods should be (roughly) equivalent as states the JavaDoc (emphasis by me):

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value *or is associated with null*, associates it with the given *non-null* value. Otherwise, replaces the associated value with the results of the given remapping function, or removes if the result is null.

In fact, there's one minor difference: if the map already contains `null` for the specified key you'd not get the value `"null and xxx"` where  `xxx` could be `null` or any other string. Instead you'd either get a NullPointerException if `value` would be `null` or just add `value`.

If you look at the source for `Map.merge(...)` you'll see this:

```
V oldValue = get(key);
V newValue = (oldValue == null) ? value :
   remappingFunction.apply(oldValue, value);
if(newValue == null) {
  remove(key);
} else {
  put(key, newValue);
}
```

To more closely resemble your first method this could be written as:

```
V oldValue = containsKey(key) ? get(key) : null;
V newValue = (oldValue == null) ? value :
   remappingFunction.apply(oldValue, value);
if(newValue == null) {
  remove(key);
} else {
  put(key, newValue);
}
```

Note that `` would be the lambda you've passed which is equivalent to `invalidMap.get(key) + " and " + newMessage` (`s + "and" + s2`). So if you replace that function with your lambda you'll get something like this:

```
V oldValue = containsKey(key) ? get(key) : null;
V newValue = (oldValue == null) ? value :
   oldValue + " and " + value; //oldValue would be s and value would be s2
if(newValue == null) {
  remove(key);
} else {
  put(key, newValue);
}
```

That being said you'd need to make sure the map doesn't contain the key with a value of `null` or handle that according to your needs.

Comment: Hmm, I have tried to confirm your last sentence, but no, this does not seem to make any difference. Still your answer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried to figure out alternatives to this question using a simple test with five variations for handling this problem in five different ways. Also tried to validate what user Thomas said on the usage of nulls.

Here is my toy validation code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException {
    Map<String, ? super CharSequence> m1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, ? super CharSequence> m2 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, ? super CharSequence> m3 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, ? super CharSequence> m4 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, StringBuilder> m5 = new HashMap<>();
    m1.put("k1", null); // validating Thomas answer to see, if this does change anything.
    addToMaps("k1", "v1",  m5, m1, m2, m3, m4);
    addToMaps("k1", "v1_1",m5, m1, m2, m3, m4);
    addToMaps("k1", "v1_3",m5, m1, m2, m3, m4);
    addToMaps("k2", "v2",  m5, m1, m2, m3, m4);
    addToMaps("k3", "v3",  m5, m1, m2, m3, m4);
    addToMaps("k3", "v3_1",m5, m1, m2, m3, m4);
    System.out.printf("m1: %s%n", m1);
    System.out.printf("m2: %s%n", m2);
    System.out.printf("m3: %s%n", m3);
    System.out.printf("m4: %s%n", m4);
    System.out.printf("m5: %s%n", m5);
}

private static void addToMaps(String key, String value,
                              Map<String, StringBuilder> builderMap,
                              Map<String, ? super CharSequence>... invalidMaps) {
    builderMap.computeIfAbsent(key, (k) -> new StringBuilder()).append(" and ").append(value);
    addToMap4(invalidMaps[3], key, value);
    addToMap1(invalidMaps[0], key, value);
    addToMap2(invalidMaps[1], key, value);
    addToMap3(invalidMaps[2], key, value);
}

private static void addToMap1(Map<String, ? super CharSequence> invalidMap, String key, String value) {
    if (invalidMap.computeIfPresent(key, (k, v) -> v + " and " + value) == null) {
        invalidMap.put(key, value);
    }
}

private static void addToMap2(Map<String, ? super CharSequence> invalidMap, String key, String newMessage) {
    if (invalidMap.containsKey(key)) {
        invalidMap.put(key, invalidMap.get(key) + " and " + newMessage);
    } else {
        invalidMap.put(key, newMessage);
    }
}

private static void addToMap4(Map<String, ? super CharSequence> invalidMap, String key, String newMessage) {
    String value = (String) invalidMap.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        invalidMap.put(key, newMessage);
    } else {
        invalidMap.put(key, value + " and " + newMessage);
    }
}

private static void addToMap3(Map<String, ? super CharSequence> invalidMap, String key, String value) {
    invalidMap.merge(key, value, (s, s2) -> s + " and " + s2);
}
```

This is what it prints for the five maps which are processed with different concatenating methods:

```
m1: {k1=v1 and v1_1 and v1_3, k2=v2, k3=v3 and v3_1}
m2: {k1=v1 and v1_1 and v1_3, k2=v2, k3=v3 and v3_1}
m3: {k1=v1 and v1_1 and v1_3, k2=v2, k3=v3 and v3_1}
m4: {k1=v1 and v1_1 and v1_3, k2=v2, k3=v3 and v3_1}
m5: {k1= and v1 and v1_1 and v1_3, k2= and v2, k3= and v3 and v3_1}
```